# Mongoose update: obtaining pushed subdocument's _id

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

Having the following `update` *query*:

```
var template = {name:'my_name', ...};
ApplicationModel.update({
        _id: idApplication,
        'templates.name': { '$ne': template.name }
    },
    {
        $push: { templates: template }
    }, function(err, raw) {
          if (err) {
              return callback(err);
          }
          ...
          callback();
    });
```

Inside `ApplicationModel` there is an array called `templates` where I push `template` objects and **Mongoose** assigns each of these objects automatically an `_id`.

Is there a way to obtain this `_id` in the query's callback function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In cases like this we usually just create the ObjectId manually, so we have it before saving:

```
var template = {name:'my_name', ...};
var myNewId  = new mongoose.Types.ObjectId();
template._id = myNewId;

ApplicationModel.update({
    _id: idApplication,
    'templates.name': { '$ne': template.name }
    },
    {
      $push: { templates: template }
    }, function(err, raw) {
      if (err) {
        return callback(err);
      }
      // myNewId is available here...

      callback();
    });
};
```

The ObjectId is anyway always created by the mongoDriver in the client, so there is in fact very little difference between doing it explicitly in code or letting the MongoDriver handle it.